# How can I parse XML with JAX

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have the following XML file and I need to parse it to Java classes with JAXB.
I can't understand, how can I parse line like this:

```
<project id="237" name="***"/>
```

The full wersion of XML:
    
                
                    10387
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    ***

```
                <start_date>2016-03-17</start_date>
                <due_date/>
                <done_ratio>30</done_ratio>
                <estimated_hours/>
                <custom_fields type="array">
                    <custom_field id="3" name="***">
                        <value>***</value>
                    </custom_field>
                    <custom_field id="16" name="***">
                        <value/>
                    </custom_field>
                    <custom_field id="33" name="***">
                        <value>***</value>
                    </custom_field>
                    <custom_field id="25" name="***">
                        <value>***</value>
                    </custom_field>
                    <custom_field id="26" name="***">
                        <value/>
                    </custom_field>
                    <custom_field id="27" name="***">
                        <value/>
                    </custom_field>
                    <custom_field id="47" name="***">
                        <value/>
                    </custom_field>
                    <custom_field id="48" name="***">
                        <value/>
                    </custom_field>
                </custom_fields>
                <created_on>***</created_on>
                <updated_on>***</updated_on>
                <closed_on/>
            </issue>
            <issue>
                <id>***</id>
                <project id="229" name="***"/>
                <tracker id="44" name="***"/>
                <status id="24" name="***"/>
                <priority id="4" name="***"/>
                <author id="23" name="***"/>
                <assigned_to id="26" name="***"/>
                <subject>***</subject>
                <description>...</description>
                <start_date>***</start_date>
                <due_date/>
                <done_ratio>20</done_ratio>
                <estimated_hours/>
                <custom_fields type="array">...</custom_fields>
                <created_on>***</created_on>
                <updated_on>***</updated_on>
                <closed_on/>
            </issue>
            ... e.t.c
        </issues>
```

I have an unmarshal exception and can't understand it.

Comment: post your code and the exception

Comment: post what you have done so far, thanks

Comment: you can read this https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

Answer (score 0):

To parse XML and HTML, Jsoup is a helpfull and easy library.

http://jsoup.org/